# How to help a 1-year-old sleep for longer than 1.5 to 2 hours at a time when we only have one bedroom?

Tags: toddler, sleep, sleep-training, bedroom, cosleeping

My 1-year-old son is only sleeping for 1.5 - 2 hours at a time. He is breastfed and we co-sleep.

I have seen similar posts on here and they recommended gentle sleep training and I have come to the conclusion that it is what I need to try, but I live in a one bedroom and don't have a space for him to get used to his own room and space. I have a pretty large room and I'm open to trying to set up his space in it and maybe add a curtain to give the feel of a separate space.

Also from what I have read having a consistant pre sleep routine and and bedtime is important but my husband works late most days and I don't think I can get that routine down.

Is there anyone in a similar situation who has had success? Any tips?

Comment: Is there any other room at all? In a one bedroom apartment, I might put the child in the living room.

Comment: Are you breastfeeding at the breast or via a bottle?

Comment: No other room and breastfeeding and the breast

Comment: Could you expound on why you cannot establish a bedtime routine? Take a bath, cuddles, read a book... Isn't this actually easier without your husband around? Put a sign on the door at bedtime, indicating Baby is asleep, so visitors don't ring the doorbell and husband will enter quietly.

Comment: Also: do you have an indication what causes your baby to wake? In our case it was always for more food and/or boobs. Do you think the baby is waking from noise and disturbance? Light?

Comment: I found the discussion and advice in the book "Precious Little Sleep" to be very useful.  Following the advice there, we managed to get our kid from feeding every few hours at night, to sleeping from 8pm to 5am without help.  As far as I can tell, it doesn't require a separate room for the kid.  It just requires reducing the number of nightly feedings by some method.  (Our doctor suggested cold turkey, once the kid was old enough - 7 months - but we weren't quite that aggressive.  It did require us to let our baby cry sometimes as he learned to go back to sleep on his own.)

Answer (score 2):

I am in a very similar situation we live in a 1.5 bedroom apt, my younger daughter is 17 months old breastfeeding and co-sleeping.

We have really started to enforce weaning and getting her in a crib to sleep, as a result she is waking up less and is better rested in the morning. My wife will breastfeed her at bed time (approx the same time every night), then I handle her any time she wakes up to gently rock her back to sleep, which has the added advantage of her not expecting milk.

Taking over a lot of the sleeping duties that my wife previously had has made it much easier to wean her.

If you can, try putting a crib in your room, and getting your husband on board with the night time routine/ responsibilities. Its not always easy - which is why it took us 17 months - but it will work eventually. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer but i hope this give some insights to people reading this question

I think the most important thing for your son to get more sleep is reduce the number of times he is fed. 
At age of 1 it is not uncommon for a kid to get 6-7 "feeding times" a day and none during the night. What worked for our son is that we made his last feeding larger (for example give him extra food from a bottle) around 11. If he wakes up during the night delay feeding him as much as possible (and if you do feed him only small amounts). Then give him more food around 6 in the morning.

After he can go 6+ hours without food. Then you can start working on sleep hygiene like building a routine and providing his own space. But if primary impulses (food) are distracting him my experience is anything else will only have limited effect.